# How to do a grid (10000 x 10000) clickable and zoomable in xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, components

I've been looking for a solution to my problem for weeks, and can't find out anything close to what I want. I need a big grid something at least 10000x10000 and even more if I can. The objective is to change the color of the cell that have been clicked. To do so users should be able to zoom in and click in one cell to modify it color. Then obviously zoom out.

I first thought to pick an image and make it clickable but to change the color of only 1 cell it would be impossible in an image.
Then I tried to do a grid with buttons inside and change their color on click, but way to long to create those inside the content page, same for labels.

Any suggestion ? 
Thanks for reading

Comment: You can change the color of only 1 pixel in an image

Comment: @Daniel so you think I should use an image and make it clickable ? Easy to zoom in and out I guess. Could work so

Comment: In my opinion, that would be better

Comment: I'm gonna try this , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this with existing UI & Layout controls.
It will be extremely slow and hard to do. 
You should use a graphic library such SkiaSharp. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/) is a good tutorial to do it. 
You might use pan & pinch gesture for zooming as well([howto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181090/xamarin-forms-pinch-and-pan-together)).

Comment: Thanks, I will look at this