# Xamarin Android Pinch and Pan not working inside Carousel View

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, pinchzoom

I have been stuck with an issue with regards to pinch and pan just on the Android platform but works well with iOS. I got my code for pinch and pan from here: [Xamarin Forms pinch and pan together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181090/xamarin-forms-pinch-and-pan-together).

I have a carousel view that has multiple images and when I try to pinch and zoom the image on Android, no event for pinch updated is fired but it works well on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the code below.

Xaml:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Frame HasShadow="True"
                   BorderColor="DarkGray"
                   CornerRadius="5"
                   Margin="20"
                   HeightRequest="300"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           FontSize="Large"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            <local:PinchToZoomContainer>
                                <local:PinchToZoomContainer.Content>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HeightRequest="250"
                           WidthRequest="250"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center">

                                    </Image>
                                </local:PinchToZoomContainer.Content>
                            </local:PinchToZoomContainer>
                         
                         
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class Page27 : ContentPage
{
    public Page27()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new Page27ViewModel();
    }
}
 public class Page27Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

}
public class Page27ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Page27Model> Images { get; set; }
    public Page27ViewModel()
    {
        Images = new ObservableCollection<Page27Model>()
        {
            new Page27Model(){ Name="1", ImageUrl="durian.png" },
            new Page27Model(){ Name="2", ImageUrl="durian.png" },
            new Page27Model(){ Name="3", ImageUrl="durian.png" },
            new Page27Model(){ Name="4", ImageUrl="durian.png" },
        };
    }
}
public class PinchToZoomContainer : ContentView
{
    double currentScale = 1;
    double startScale = 1;
    double xOffset = 0;
    double yOffset = 0;

    public PinchToZoomContainer()
    {
        var pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
        pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(pinchGesture);
    }

    void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Started)
        {
            // Store the current scale factor applied to the wrapped user interface element,
            // and zero the components for the center point of the translate transform.
            startScale = Content.Scale;
            Content.AnchorX = 0;
            Content.AnchorY = 0;
        }
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Running)
        {
            // Calculate the scale factor to be applied.
            currentScale += (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
            currentScale = Math.Max(1, currentScale);

            // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
            // so get the X pixel coordinate.
            double renderedX = Content.X + xOffset;
            double deltaX = renderedX / Width;
            double deltaWidth = Width / (Content.Width * startScale);
            double originX = (e.ScaleOrigin.X - deltaX) * deltaWidth;

            // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
            // so get the Y pixel coordinate.
            double renderedY = Content.Y + yOffset;
            double deltaY = renderedY / Height;
            double deltaHeight = Height / (Content.Height * startScale);
            double originY = (e.ScaleOrigin.Y - deltaY) * deltaHeight;

            // Calculate the transformed element pixel coordinates.
            double targetX = xOffset - (originX * Content.Width) * (currentScale - startScale);
            double targetY = yOffset - (originY * Content.Height) * (currentScale - startScale);

            // Apply translation based on the change in origin.
            Content.TranslationX = targetX.Clamp(-Content.Width * (currentScale - 1), 0);
            Content.TranslationY = targetY.Clamp(-Content.Height * (currentScale - 1), 0);

            // Apply scale factor
            Content.Scale = currentScale;
        }
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Completed)
        {
            // Store the translation delta's of the wrapped user interface element.
            xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
            yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
        }
    }
}
public static class DoubleExtensions
{
    public static double Clamp(this double self, double min, double max)
    {
        return Math.Min(max, Math.Max(self, min));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @Wendy, thanks for the response. I tried it but it still does not trigger the pinch updated function unfortunately. It works perfectly on iOS but only on Android this issue appears. Any idea why so? Thanks mate!

Comment: I have uploaded my screenshot. Please check it. It works on Android.

Comment: Hey buddy @Wendy, I am sorry to let you know that I have updated all my nugets for Android to the latest versions but still I have no luck. Can't seem to understand why it is not working for me.

Comment: I used the latest version of the Xamarin.forms. It works. But sometimes the scroll of carouselview would make the zoom in and zoom out not obvious enough. You could reset the height and width of image bigger to recheck.